# dynamic cell height in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

i have a problem with dynamic cell height.this my code, cell is not dynamic height, hơ to make it dynamic (not autolayout). thanks

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell


        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0 , 0, cell.frame.width, cell.frame.height))
        label.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eget libero enim. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec tempor posuere augue. Pellentesque at nibh quam. Mauris at nulla id enim elementum fermentum sit amet at dolor. Phasellus quis purus eu enim ullamcorper porttitor. Praesent consectetur lorem non ligula elementum rhoncus. Pellentesque diam dolor, gravida eget quam at, consequat luctus elit. Curabitur posuere augue sed nunc ornare semper. Nunc ut lorem vitae ligula dictum dapibus quis eget ex. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas."
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.sizeToFit()
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        cell.contentView.addSubview(label)

        return cell
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**in SWIFT 3.0**

First of all you have set your label constraint like leading,traling, top and bottom

then after set constraint in your **ViewController.swift** file's

method **ViewDidLoad()** write this Code.

yourTableview.estimatedRowHeight = 83.0

yourTableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: @shuuichiakai if it's useful then make upvote thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `boundingRectWithSize` method of `NSString` or `NSAttributedString`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let text: NSString = ""
    let size = CGSize(width: widthOfYourCell, height: CGFloat.max)
    let attributes: [String : AnyObject] = [
        NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
        // etc.
    ]
    let rect = text.boundingRectWithSize(size, options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context: nil)
    return rect.height
}
```

Comment: @shuuichiakai you're welcome. Accept the answer, if it helps you)

Answer (score 1):

you must add this code :

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.f; // As your mind.
    }
```

Comment: if i use autolayout, it's ok, but im not use autolayout :)

Answer (score 0):

just add this two delegate method of tableview and see the magic.keep in mind not to give fixed height of any property.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
return 500
}
```

Comment: if i use autolayout, it's ok, but im not use autolayout

Comment: if you will not use autolayout than you have to calculate height of all property in cell and give the height of each cell while returning cell.